# Explanation for operator << overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand how operator overloads works.

I want to code it so that I can write

```
Log(Log::LEVEL_ERR) << "fatal error: " << 13 ;
```

And for both the string and the number the overloaded operator is used.

I now have

```
class Log{
  public:
    std::ostream& operator<<(char const*);
}

std::ostream& Log::operator<<(char const* text){
  if (Log::isToWrite()) {
    printLevel();
    std::cout << text;
  }
  return std::cout;
}
```

This only get's me the string but not the number, why?

**Edit**
@bitmask Just to be clear, you mean implement like this:

```
class Log{
  public:
    friend  Log& operator<<(Log& in, char const* text);
}

friend  Log& operator<<(Log& in, char const* text){
  if (in.isToWrite()) {
    in.printLevel();
    std::cout << text;
  }
  return std::cout;
}
```

Because I get these everywhere now:

> error: Semantic Issue: Invalid operands to binary expression ('Log' and 'const char [15]')

Maybe this is really simple but can you spell it out for me?
I'm really not getting it.

Comment: because it takes a char*, and an int is not implicitly convertable to char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you returned an `ostream&`, the next `<<` operator matches `operator<<(ostream&, int)`.  You should `return *this;` (type is `Log&`) instead, so that the next `<<` operator matches an operator defined for your class.

Comment: But then I get `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Log' and 'int') [3]`

Comment: @kotoko: Yes, because you only implemented `operator<<` to accept a `char const*`, but you try to pass it an `int`. Implement your `operator<<` as a template.

Comment: @bitmask I'm not saying that isn't a good idea but I never worked with templates before. Is there a way to do it using a free form friend function?

Comment: @kotoko: Well, yes. Implement one for `char const*` and one for `int`. But that's what it will be limited to, then.